# Swift Making a generic function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, function

I'm trying to write a function which can take my textField and buttons then add the custom layer features I want. I was wondering if its possible to use a parameter which can take a textField or button instead of having to add them all out?

```
setupShadows(textField: emailTextField, button1: submitButton, button2: skipButton)
```

Here is my generic function I made:

```
private func setupShadows(textField: UITextField?, button1: UIButton?, button2: UIButton?) {
    textField?.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 18/255, green: 18/255, blue: 18/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    textField?.layer.borderWidth = 1
    textField?.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    textField?.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    textField?.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
    textField?.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    textField?.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
    textField?.clipsToBounds = false
    
    button1?.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 18/255, green: 18/255, blue: 18/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    button1?.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button1?.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button1?.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    button1?.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
    button1?.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    button1?.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
    button1?.clipsToBounds = false
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you want generics, an extension might be better

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but I think you can write it like this

```
private func setupShadows(object: UIView) {
    object.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 18/255, green: 18/255, blue: 18/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    object.layer.borderWidth = 1
    object.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    object.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    object.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
    object.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    object.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
    object.clipsToBounds = false
}
```

Comment: Oooh, OP's question makes so much more sense now

Comment: If this isn't a generic function what would you call this?

Comment: No, this is not a generic function. This is just a reusable function. A generic function is intended to be used by a variety of different objets.

Here's an analogy, which I hope can clear things up:

A cup is a generic container for anything. Could be glitter, rocks, or milk. Where as a water bottle, is a reusable container. Can be only used by liquid, since it has to pass through the nozzle. Does that make sense? You couldn't put rocks in there, because it'd be useless. You could technically put glitter in there, but it probably won't work like you'd expect since eventually it'd clog